# Дистрибутив Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu

Kubuntu русифицирована? Где скачать дистрибутив русский?

Answer (score 1):

Все разновидности Ubuntu достаточно русифицированы. Сначала скачиваете последний дистрибутив с [зеркала Яндекс](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/kubuntu/) и устанавливаете себе на машину. После того, как завершите установку, идете в K -> Параметры системы -> Язык и стандарты, нажимаете на Выбрать язык системы и вводите пароль. Либо открываете терминал и выполняете команду

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-ru kde-l10n-ru language-pack-kde-ru language-pack-kde-ru-base language-pack-ru language-pack-ru-base language-support-ru myspell-ru language-pack-gnome-ru-base language-pack-gnome-ru openoffice.org-help-ru openoffice.org-l10n-ru manpages-ru
```

и перезагружаетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно, основные дистрибутивы ubuntu включают русский язык. Язык достаточно выбрать на этапе установки.Найти и скачать Ubuntu - вообще никакой проблемы не составляет - ресурсов куча, хочешь - напрямую, хочешь - через торренты. Вот, в частности, русскоязычный ресурс где выложены основные дистрибутивы kubuntu- [ссылка](http://kubuntu.ru/download) Либо можно скачать Ubuntu с официального сайта и затем выбрать и установить любую оболочку - GNOME или KDE (с KDE, соответственно, и будет kubuntu)